# Getting `Request had invalid authentication credentials` when using service account json key file in Go app

Tags: authentication, go, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing a Go app on a GCP project and I'm using google cloud logging service. I'm having problems in running the app since it's saying that I have invalid authentication credentials when I'm using a service account json key.

Here's the code snippet having the error:

```
c, cErr := Load(".env")
    if cErr != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not load config: %s", cErr)
        return
    }

    // initializes logger which writes to stdout
    ctx := context.Background()
    opt := option.WithCredentialsFile(c.GoogleApplicationCredentials);
    loggerClient, clientErr := logging.NewClient(ctx, "poc-projects-01", opt)
    if clientErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(clientErr)
    }
```

And here's the definition of the `Load()` function:

```
func Load(file string) (*Config, error) {
    viper.SetConfigFile(file)
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    viper.AutomaticEnv()
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    c := &Config{
        GoogleApplicationCredentials: viper.GetString("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"),
    }

    return c, nil
}
```

I have a `.env` file with the following content:
`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=json/path-to-json.json`

I don't know why it's saying token expired even though this is the only service account json key I have on GCP, and on my local machine.

Comment: Where is running your app? On Google Cloud? On your computer?

Comment: It's on my computer

Comment: So, do not use service account key file, it's not really secure. Prefer the first line of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) and make sure you have that set to the right project.

Check whether `GOOGLEAPPLICATIONSCREDENTALS` is set with valid JSON key and the environment variable are correctly set, for checking run the below command

```
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

If the command does not return the correct path to the JSON key, you can set the environment variable with this command:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/json/key.json
```

Once you have verified that the JSON key is valid and the environment variable is correctly set, you should be able to run your application.Alternatively, you can try to delete the .env file and then recreate it with the [service account json key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys), which should re-generate the token and make it valid.

Attaching troubleshooting [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/troubleshooting?agent=any&category=any#invalid-auth-cred) for reference.